# Xcode 5 Show Overlaps During Navigation of Controllers

Tags: ios7, xcode5

When i have ran my application on Xcode 5 Navigation controllers overlaps during push to another controller what the solution ??
i.e:

[image: Root Controller]

[image: push to another controller]

how to get rid of this effect?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is like this,

**Loading a new viewController on tap to `tableViewCell`**

[image]

Then your solution is to give some `backgroundColor` to your `newViewControllers` view.

Like this :

[image: WhiteBAckground]      [image: redBackground]

hope that helps.